# Add attribute to "related product" filter grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to add an extra attribute let say "Brand" into related product grid to filter products. I have found and implemented this code below but it shows that attribute only in Manage product grid, not in single product related product grid.

My system.xml file has this code

```
 <filter_attribute>
   <label>Attribute to filter by</label>
   <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
   <source_model>inchoo_product_filter/attributes</source_model>
   <sort_order>2</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
 </filter_attribute>
```

and model

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Productfilter_Model_Attributes
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $ignoreAttributes = array('sku', 'name', 'attribute_set_id', 'type_id', 'qty', 'price', 'status', 'visibility');

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->addVisibleFilter();

        $result = array();
        foreach ($collection as $model) {
            if(in_array($model->getAttributeCode(), $ignoreAttributes)) {
                continue;
            }
            $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array($model->getAttributeCode()));
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($model->getAttributeCode(), array('gt' => 0));

            if(count($productCollection->getData()) > 0) {
                $result[] = array('value' => $model->getAttributeCode(), 'label'=>$model->getFrontendLabel());
            }

        }

       return $result;

    }
}
```

This attribute is showing in manage product.
[image]

But not in the related product.
[image]

Please help.

I resloved this

If anybody else facing this issue here the solution how I solved blow.

Go to this file -> Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Related.php

And paste this code below

```
$attribute  = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('brand');
        $preOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

        $options = array();
        foreach($preOptions as $option) {
            if($option['value']) {
                $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
        }

        $this->addColumn('brand', array(
             'header'  => $this->__($attribute->getFrontendLabel()),
             'width'   => '100px',
             'type'    => 'options',
             'index'   => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
             'options' => $options,
        ));
```

You can also get your custom attribute just change the "brand" identifier to your own created in custom attribute.